# PHP regex replace phrase + number

Tags: php, regex

My string is

```
"http://exanmple.com/katalogas/?is_search=1&type=list&filter=search_1&activity=&activity_id=&activity=langai&activity_id=&region_id=-2&page_no=2"
```

I want replace from string all `page_no=2` number can change, phrase  is static `page_no`

What I try:

```
/\&page_no=[0-9]\b/i
```

Comment: Remove from string - replace with empty spaces

Comment: So check the following answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match this regex:

```
/(?<=\?)page_no=\d+&|&page_no=\d+\b/i
```

**Code:**

```
$url = preg_replace('/(?<=\?)page_no=\d+&|&page_no=\d+\b/i', '', $url);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dG5pA9/10)

Comment: You should add an optional `&` at the end of the pattern to avoid `&&` or `?&` when `page_no` isn't the last parameter.

Comment: Thanks, yes I realized that a `&` also need to be removed, edited now.